# How to convert an XML file to an hardcoded object?

Tags: xml, typescript

I have an XML file like this:

```
<Obj something1="test" something2="test">
    <children something1="test" />
        <something2>test</something2>
    </children>
</Obj>
```

And want to convert it into an hardcoded object like this (Typeschript):

```
var Obj = {
    something1: "test",
    something2: "test",
    children: [{
            something1: "test",
            something2: "test"
        }]
};
```

Is there a tool for doing that?

Comment: Where are you reading the XML from

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Parsing_and_serializing_XML

Comment: @Amy im not looking for serializing it.

Comment: @Luthervd Sublime Text 2

Comment: @maxmusterman maybe you should scroll down to see how to deserialize it then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tool you are looking for is called [XSLT (W3Schools)](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xsl_intro.asp).
The following XSLT-1.0 stylesheet creates the output you were looking for:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="text" omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="no"/>

  <xsl:template match="Obj">
    <xsl:text>var Obj = { &#x0A;</xsl:text>
      <xsl:for-each select="@* | *[count(child::*) = 0]">
        <xsl:value-of select="local-name()" />: <xsl:value-of select="." />
        <xsl:if test="position() != last()">,</xsl:if>
      </xsl:for-each>
      <xsl:if test="count(child::*) > 0">,</xsl:if>
      <xsl:apply-templates />
    };
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="children">
    <xsl:text>children: [{&#xa;</xsl:text>
      <xsl:for-each select="@* | *[count(child::*) = 0]">
        <xsl:value-of select="local-name()" />: <xsl:value-of select="." />
        <xsl:if test="position() != last()">,</xsl:if>
      </xsl:for-each>
    }]
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Output:**

```
var Obj = { 
    something1: test,something2: test,
    children: [{
        something1: test,something2: test
    }]
    };
```

If you could use XSLT-2.0 or XSLT-3.0, this stylesheet could be simplified even further.